# Is switching quantifiers allowed in this instance?

Tags: logic, logical-validity

In Logic In Computer Science (2nd Edition - Michael Huth and Mark Ryan), exercise 2.4.12.k is the following:

> For each of the formulas of predicate logic below, either find a model which
>   does not satisfy it, or prove it is valid.

This one is difficult:

> (∀x ∃y (P(x) → Q(y))) → (∃y ∀x (P(x) → Q(y)))

Not only am I not sure how to prove this, I'm not sure whether it is valid or not. I came across this question when revising for an exam and always hit a dead end with it.

Any suggestions or insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The key issue here is whether switching quantifiers is okay. Turn the top-level implication around and see what happens then.

As for this formula, think about what the left- resp. the right-hand side say.

- Left: "Every $x$ has a $y$ so that... holds."
- Right: "There is a $y$ so that ... holds for all $x$."

In particular, the left-hand side allows *different* $y$ -- one for each $x$ -- while the right-hand side requires a *single* $y$.

With this off the table, try to figure out whether

$\qquad \left(\forall x. \exists y. P(x,y)\right) \to \left(\exists y. \forall x. P(x,y)\right)$

holds for all predicates $P$. If so, your original questions is answered, and if not it should be easy to modify a counter-example to have the necessary form of an implication.

> For the simplified formula, there is a simple counter-example: every natural number has a successor, but there is no natural number that is successor to all natural numbers.

Try to utilise this before lifting the next spoiler!

> No luck? Well, that is to be expected. The "simplified" formula was a trap as it is not really a simplified formula, as you have hopefully figured out. It allows you to set $x$ and $y$ in relation which your formula does not: the (inner) implications can be read as disjunction, i.e. $\lnot P(x) \lor Q(y)$, so $P$ and $Q$ can fulfill the disjunction independently of another.

Can you prove that the formula holds now?

> If the left-hand side is fulfilled -- if it is not, the whole formula is trivially fulfilled -- all $x$ fulfill $\lnot P(x)$ or there is (at least) one $y$ that fulfills $Q(y)$ (to rescue the failing $x$). In either case (they can overlap!) the right hand side is fulfilled. In particular, if $\lnot P(x)$ is true for all $x$, $y$ can be chosen arbitrarily (on the right-hand side), else choose one of the rescuers. Be aware that the empty element domain -- if allowed -- is a special case.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer! Note that (and I hope this doesn't give too much away) the reasoning only holds in classical logic.

Answer (score 1):

consider the empty {P,Q}-structure ...

Comment: For empty domains, the formula holds because $\exists y. \dots$ is always false.

Comment: but the first part is alway true.

Comment: No, it is not. *There is no* $y$ to fulfill it; you can fulfill it with arbitrary $Q$ if $P$ is well-chosen, but there as to be one element in $y$'s domain to fulfill the formula. And -- I am not sure how you meant "always" -- you can find plenty of models that do not fulfill the left-hand side, e.g. $P(x) = T$ and $Q(x) = F$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Raphael For an empty domain, the formula is always false, because $\forall x$ is never instantiated, hence the left-hand side of the implication is true.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to express $(\forall x, \exists y, (P(x) \rightarrow Q(y))) \to (\exists y, \forall x, (P(x) \rightarrow Q(y)))$ in English:

> Premise: suppose that for every $x$, there is a $y$ such that $P(x)$ implies $Q(y)$.
>   Conclusion: then there is a $y$ such that for every $x$, $P(x)$ implies $Q(y)$.

Suppose the premise holds, and suppose that we have found an $x_0$ such that $P(x_0)$ holds. Then there is a $y_0$ such that $Q(y_0)$ holds. There is nothing specific to $x_0$ about $y_0$: if there is some other $x$ that satisfies $P(x)$, then we can take that same $y_0$, we still have $Q(y_0)$, hence we still have that $P(x)$ implies $Q(y)$.

Or, in other words, if the premise holds and there is an $x_0$ such that $P(x_0)$ holds, then the conclusion holds. We have proved that the formula is always true under the additional assumption $\exists x_0, P(x_0)$.

So all we need to do now is look at what happens if that additional assumption does not hold. By the principle of excluded middle and the well-known principles of inversion of negation and quantifiers, the opposite assumption is $\forall x, \neg P(x)$. Since $P(x)$ never holds, the implication $P(x) \rightarrow Q(y)$ always holds. Are we finished? Almost. If we take any $y_0$ in the model, then the formula $\forall x, (P(x) \rightarrow Q(y_0))$ holds. So the conclusion is true in every non-empty model, hence the formula holds in every non-empty model.

If you allow an empty model, then the formula does not hold, because the premise is true ($\forall x, …$ is vacuously true) and the conclusion is false ($\exists y, …$ is vacuously false).